# Is there any kind of monument or marker for the Tropic of Cancer along the coast on the east side of Taiwan?

Tags: taiwan, landmarks, locate-this, geography, coastline

On my way down the west coast of Taiwan some weeks ago I passed a large monument marking the Tropic of Cancer. The site itself was a bit cheesy but just having a monument at all to mark the tropic and have a rest stop at is still nice.

Now I'm heading up the east coast and I thought heading for a similar marker, even if smaller, might make a cool goal for today or tomorrow.

I want to head up the main route closest to the coast, highway 11.

But so far the only Tropic of Cancer monument I can find on the east coast is 50km inland at [Ruisui Township](http://www.erv-nsa.gov.tw/user/Article.aspx?Lang=2&SNo=03000138).

Is there one on route 11 or very close to it? Also right on the coast is great if route 11 is a bit away from the coast at that point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Jing Pu Tropic of Cancer landmark](http://tour-hualien.hl.gov.tw/Portal/Content.aspx?lang=0&p=005060001&area=5&id=9).  It's located just off route 11 and is marked on Google Maps as a landmark.

Comment: Man I can't find it anywhere around Jingpu, which is where I was already looking for ages on Google Maps before I asked here ... Oh it seems to be "靜浦北迴歸線界標" which doesn't contain any word for tropic etc that I know of such as 热带 and I didn't spot it in the background of the pic that Google Maps uses.

Comment: Aha so I need to learn the word "回歸線" (-:

Comment: We can trust this avatar: those penguins are master travelers! +1

Comment: Kowalski!  Next destination!